# How do I make AcySms manual cron job in cPanel work?

Tags: cron, cpanel, acymailing

When setting up AcySMS, there are few option for the cron job. "Web cron" runs at the fastest interval of 15 minutes, way too slow for me.

I have opted for "manual cron", and am given the following "cron URL" `https://www.followmetrading.com/index.php?option=com_acysms&ctrl=cron`

Putting that into the cPanel cron job manager just leaves me with an error everytime the cron attempts to run:
`/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: http://www.followmetrading.com/index.php?option=com_acysms: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that the following command executes the script properly.

`curl --request GET 'https://www.followmetrading.com/index.php?option=com_acysms&ctrl=cron&no_html=1' >/dev/null 2>&1`

**Note**: ensure the URL is surrounded by `' '` otherwise it seems to miss everything from the `&` onward.

**Note**: `>/dev/null 2>&1` makes sure there is no email trail.